# Rust to Python custom type covertion with pyo3

Tags: rust, pyo3

I'm trying to create a Python package with Pyo3 & Rust.

in one of my functions, I'm trying to return a tch::Tensor type though not sure how to transform it so Python will be familiar with it.

here's what I've tried so far:

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use tch::{Tensor, Kind};
use tch::TchError;
use pyo3::exceptions::PyValueError;

struct PyTchError(TchError);

impl From<PyTchError> for PyErr {
    fn from(error: PyTchError) -> Self {
        PyValueError::new_err("error while resizing image")
    }
}

impl From<TchError> for PyTchError {
    fn from(other: TchError) -> Self {
        Self(other)
    }
}


#[pyfunction]
fn create_tensor() -> Result<Tensor, PyTchError> {
    let res = Tensor::from_slice(&[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).to_kind(Kind::Float);
    Ok(res)
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn pyo3_utils(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(create_tensor, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

which resulted in the error -

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<tch::Tensor, PyTchError>: OkWrap<_>` is not satisfied   --> src/lib.rs:42:1    | 42 |
> #[pyfunction]    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `OkWrap<_>` is not implemented for `Result<tch::Tensor, PyTchError>`    |    = help: the
> trait `OkWrap<T>` is implemented for `Result<T, E>`

I then tried to implement the IntoPy Trait:

```
struct PyTensor(Tensor);

impl IntoPy<Py<PyAny>> for PyTensor {
    fn into_py(self, py: Python<'_>) -> Py<PyAny> {
        self.0
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
fn create_tensor() -> Result<PyTensor, PyTchError> {
    let res = Tensor::from_slice(&[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).to_kind(Kind::Float);
    Ok(PyTensor(res))
}
```

but still getting an error -

> error[E0308]: mismatched types   --> src/lib.rs:26:9    | 25 |     fn
> into_py(self, py: Python<'_>) -> Py {    |
> --------- expected `Py<PyAny>` because of return type 26 |         self.0    |         ^^^^^^ expected `Py<PyAny>`, found `Tensor`    |
> = note: expected struct `Py<PyAny>`
> found struct `tch::Tensor`
>
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `Result<tch::Tensor, PyTchError>: OkWrap<_>` is not satisfied   --> src/lib.rs:45:1    | 45 |
> #[pyfunction]    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `OkWrap<_>` is not implemented for `Result<tch::Tensor, PyTchError>`    |    = help: the
> trait `OkWrap<T>` is implemented for `Result<T, E>`

any ideas how to convert Tensor to python correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IntoPy` implementation doesn't make any sense: it's supposed to return a `PyObject`, you're returning a `Tensor`, the entire issue is that `Tensor` is not a python-compatible type.

In this case however it doesn't really matter: [tch actually provides a pyo3 bridge](https://github.com/LaurentMazare/tch-rs/tree/main/pyo3-tch), so you can just depend on pyo3-tch and return a `PyTensor`.